# Question Regarding number of frames required for multilevel page tables

Tags: operating-systems, paging

I have a problem and I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this, description
[image: The problem statement]
so as you can see it is given a 3 level paging system with 8 bit page index on every level, now I break down logical address as ( 8+8+8+12 ) first 24 bits being page no bits in logical address space, and 12 being page offset bits, with that I come to know there should be 2<sup>24</sup> entries in level 0 page table, and I get 2<sup>8</sup> entries per page so we have 2<sup>16</sup> frames or pages in level 0 page table, and to index those 2<sup>16</sup> pages we need 2<sup>16</sup> entries in level 1 page table, by dividing 2<sup>8</sup> we get 2<sup>8</sup> frames in level 1 page table and the same number of entries in level 2 page table and on again dividing by 2<sup>8</sup> we get 1 frame for level 2 page table, so in total I expect the number of frames to be  2<sup>16</sup>+2<sup>8</sup>+1 only for page tables as required by the question, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check the solution provided?

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  This is required under our rules: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!